# SQL named instance cannot be connected by a specific user

Tags: sql-server-2008

SQL server 2008 R2. 
It has default instance running and a couple of named instance.
- I can connect to both default instance and named instances.
- User can connect to default instance but he is not able to connect to named instances.
- I asked the user to connect "tcp:ServerIP\instancename" and it works

I thought then it could be that UDP port 1434 is not allowed (which is important for names instance connection), but I am not able to connect the usual way (servername\instancename)
My system administrator tells me all the ports are allowed to this hosting network on the SQL boxes including the UDP ports.

I have 2 questions:
1. What could be blocking the user/s in a particular network not be able to connect to it?
2. Is it bad if I allow the user to connect to is using "tcp:ServerIP\instancename" ? Why don't usually people don't use this? 
3. What does it mean when a user can connect to an instance using "tcp:ServerIP\instancename" but not "ServerIP\instancename"

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is Browser service up and running ? That is required for connecting to named instance.

Comment: What does "not able to connect" mean? What is the exact error message? If it's an 18456 error, [what is the *state* in SQL Server's error log](https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456)?

Comment: It is error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance required. http://screencast.com/t/Kvbic3WlNq

Comment: SQL browser service is running. It doesn't look like it is instance specific. There is a generic one running. http://screencast.com/t/eh0qIvSntY0Q (here is a screenshot. I  blocked the domain name)

Comment: can you connect using the IP?

Comment: No. "ServerIP\Instancename" does not work. but "tcp:ServerIP\instancename" works

Comment: I'd check sql server configuration and see if 'named pipes' is enabled.

Comment: Yes. All except VIA are enabled (Shared memory, TCP/IP, Named Pipes)